# Examining the Windows Store apps AppxManifest at Runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I try to load the AppxManifest at Runtime to read out the Version of the app. I fond this article:
http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2013/01/examining-the-windows-store-apps-appxmanifest-at-runtime/#comments

I tried the line from the post:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("AppxManifest.xml", LoadOptions.None);
```

But this will throw me the following exception:

```
{System.Xml.XmlException: An internal error has occurred.
   at System.Xml.XmlXapResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at MyMedi.Src.Utilities.GetVersion()
   at MyMedi.WindowsPhone.Test.Src.UtilitiesTest.Utilities_GetVersionTest()}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to, but you could try loading the document with the [ms-appx:// uri schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx) in the file reference.

There's a much easier way to achieve your goal, though.

```
Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;
PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

var versionString = string.Format(
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
               version.Major,
               version.Minor,
               version.Build,
               version.Revision);
```

Comment: It does, as far as I know, and that would be the proper way to load it.